# 'with X and Y' where 'Y' has no article

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

Okay, a brief grammatical scuffle has broken out on a forum I frequent, where someone used the expression 'with whiskey and cigar', and someone else claimed it was grammatically incorrect, suggesting that 'cigar' should either be pluralised or preceded with 'a'.

I'm absolutely *convinced* that it's correct as it is, but I'm afraid I don't have the in-depth knowledge to adequately explain why, so if someone could clarify this for me, I'd be most appreciative. Thanks! :)

EDIT: For completeness, the expression in question is actually the 'tagline' of the forum in question 'Where gaming happens with whiskey and cigar'.

Comment: Context please. At least post a complete sentence.

Comment: After your edit, I'd say it's plain wrong. Should be cigars IMHO.

Comment: "I'm absolutely convinced that it's correct as it is," so am I. Ask anyone who objects: *Why?* -- it's for them to try and argue their case and, eventually, fail.

Comment: Kris - no. I would disagree with you entirely. It is grammatically incorrect, as per well known rules of the English language. The author of this line should justify why they aren't following the rules.

Comment: Sounds like they are just trying to be poetic. It's a bit like "with gun in hand" - I'm sure I've seen this as an expression.

Comment: "with whiskey and cigar" is incorrect, or least extremely archaic and odd-sounding. Should be "with whiskey and cigars" or even "with whiskey and a cigar".

Answer (score 1):

As it stands,

> I brought whiskey and cigars

or

> I brought whiskey and a cigar

are correct. *I brought whiskey and cigar* is not really correct but understandable. It could be correct if "whiskey and cigar" is an expression.

Also

> A whiskey and cigar gaming club

is ok

UPDATE:

> Where gaming happens with whiskey and cigar

is grammatically incorrect.

Should be

> Where gaming happens with whiskey and cigars

or if you only get one cigar per game

> Where gaming happens with whiskey and a cigar

Comment: Yeah, apologies - original post has since been clarified.

Comment: Please see update. Your tagline is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The zero article (that is, no article at all) is sometimes found in parallel structures of the type shown in your example. A couple of similar examples, taken from the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’, are:

> Thankfully, it has turned out all right for mother and baby.

and

> This broadly relates to communications between lawyer and client.

The device was once used by writers of travel books about the British Empire in titles such as ‘Adventures in Zambechuland with Gun and Rod’.

So, yes, it is grammatical, but so, too, would be 'Where gaming happens with a whiskey and a cigar'.

Comment: Grammatical yes, but I'm concerned about the meaning; in 'With Rod and Line along the Alimentary Canal' the implication is that you are using one fishing rod. Sharing one cigar round has schoolboy implications the forum may not desire.

Comment: @Tim: if three people go "fishing with rod and reel", they probably have more than one fishing rod between them. But I don't think anybody says "fishing with rods and reels".

Comment: @Barrie - that's along the lines I'm thinking as well - I've seen similar examples used many times in the past in a variety of different works, but have been unable to adequately explain why it works.

Comment: A similar example would be _With whiskey in one hand and cigar in the other, he proceeded to tell us his story_.